# Using OWL with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, rdf, semantic-web, owl

I'm looking for a way to create/edit an ontology in python and perform some reasoning with it. From what I've read OWL seems to be the tool best suited for my project. At the moment I'm using python 2.7.5 and all of the libraries I've seen aren't maintained or supported anymore. Is there one out there that is still active?

Comment: You may want to explore [rdflib](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib) or [pyRDFa](http://dev.w3.org/2004/PythonLib-IH/Doc-pyRdfa/pyRdfa-module.html) although I'm uncertain they do exactly what you want. Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11154269/735204) may be of some use.

Comment: This is a useful question, but it's off topic of Stack Overflow, since "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: That said, you might have better luck at http://answers.semanticweb.com.  It seems to be slow at the moment, but a [Google search for `site:answers.semanticweb.com owl python`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aanswers.semanticweb.com+owl+python&oq=site%3Aanswers.semanticweb.com+owl+python&aqs=chrome..69i64.12608j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) makes it look like there are some relevant questions and answers for you.

Answer (score 0):

[kglab](https://github.com/DerwenAI/kglab) may be worth exploring, although it's using rdflib under the hood.

There are a few write-ups on inference and reasoning with kglab, including [this one](https://github.com/DerwenAI/kglab/blob/802153dc7bacaa9023b8663a8edf3c497d8bb379/docs/infer.md), as well as notebooks ([this one](https://derwen.ai/docs/kgl/ex7_0/) and [this one](https://derwen.ai/docs/kgl/ex7_1/)).